# Give users "Debug folder" of windows form application or published setup: Which is the better option

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, setup-deployment

I have to give my **windows form application** to other users and We are using **shared drive**.
I am not sure which is the better option: *Giving users "Debug folder" of windows form application **or** published setup*.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense in its current form...

Comment: Why can't you give them a deployment with a setup.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are seveal options available for installing the application on the user's machine, instead of simply allowing them to run it from a network share.

One option is to use [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to generate a setup file, which can be accessed from a network share.

Compared with giving users access to the debug folder, it allows better control over updating (you can compile and run debug versions as much as you want, then when you're ready, publish it to your users, who will automatically get the latest version). It also allows for giving the users an optimised version of the program, without additional debugging overhead. It also manages installing dependencies, such as the .net framework.

For other advantages see here: http://www.msigeek.com/330/advantages-of-clickonce-deployment

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4(v=VS.90).aspx